# Accessing images form table

Tags: php, rendering

Look at the following code:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $r => $stringrow) {
    $rowarray=explode("#",$stringrow);
}
```

`$_SESSION['cart']` contains the  row of concatenated values the separator is "#". Which I got from the previous page (as you can see they are inserted in a session.) I am exploding `$stringrow` to get an array called `$rowarray`. Everything is fine till here. The problem is this `$rowarray[]` contains two array elements, each of which contain concatenated imageurls separated by "#". The concatenated image urls are in  `$rowarray[11]` and  `$rowarray[12]`. I am again exploding `$rowarray[11]` and `$rowarray[12]`. trying to access each imageurl. But it's not happening. till now I have used innumerable echos to see the content of the imageurl array but every time it's showing 'Array'. as the value.

Comment: Hi Pushan. Can you take a quick look at [markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) to older questions?

Comment: Your questions need some serious work. Please pay attention to the formatting hints given on the right-hand side of the screen as you compose your posts. Also, please keep in mind that separating your thoughts into paragraphs (using white space, like new lines) makes things significantly easier to read and understand. You're also more likely to get help this way.

Comment: Include sample of what is in the session variable

Answer (score 0):

To view the contents of arrays, try using either `var_dump($array)` or `print_r($array)`.  They'll show you the type and contents of whatever variable you feed to them.  It makes debugging oddly nested arrays much easier.